# Look through a HTML textbox for certain substrings, then replace them with other strings

Tags: javascript

I'm making an app for a family member who fills in forms as part of her job. It requires her to fill in long bits of text at a time, which becomes repetitive and annoying. I have had the idea of writing short codenames (like "GDS" for "Good Domestic Standard"). I want the program to look through the textbox and search for certain (defined) codenames and replace them with their "proper meanings". So far, I have this:

```
<html>

<style type="text/css">
h1.title
{
    font-size: 80px;
    font-family: "Verdana";
    font-weight: bolder;
}

body
{
    background: rgb(200,400,200);
}

p.main
{
    font-size: 31px;
    font-family: "Verdana";
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
}
textarea
{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 600px;
}   
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getBoxText()
{
    var boxText = document.getElementById("textBox").value // Get what's in the TextBox.
    document.getElementById("bottomText").innerHTML = boxText
}
</script>

<head>
    <h1 align="middle" class="title">Test Page for BoxScan</h1>
</head>

<body>
    <p class="main">Welcome to BoxScan Test Page!</p>
    <textarea id="textBox">Input your text here!</textarea>
    <br>
    <button onclick="getBoxText()">Submit</button>
    <br>
    <h1 id="bottomText">Blank</h1>
</body>


</html>
```

Obviously, this bit is the part in question:

```
var boxText = document.getElementById("textBox").value // Get what's in the TextBox.
document.getElementById("bottomText").innerHTML = boxText
```

This works, but now how would I look through AND REPLACE the strings I want? Let's use `GDS` for an example, which means `Good Domestic Standard`.

Comment: just for clarification: what you want is to enter a text that might contain several instances of these (possibly different) strings and replace each by its expanded version, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tasked with your need here, I would create a mapping between the abbreviated form and the expanded form, and use `String.replace()` to replace abbreviations as they are found.

Having this mapping also allows you to easily add new ones, and also easily allow the user to save them own mappings. (Using LocalStorage, IndexedDB, or similar)

```js
var mapping = {};
mapping['GDS'] = 'Good Domestic Standard';
mapping['PHP'] = 'Personal Home Page';
mapping['JS'] = 'JavaScript';

document.getElementById('replace').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {

  var newString = (function(map, oldString) {
    Object.keys(map).forEach(function(key) {
      oldString = oldString.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + key + '\\b', 'g'), map[key]);
    });
    return oldString;
  }(mapping, document.getElementById('input').value));

output.value = newString;

});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 600px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 3px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button id="replace">Replace</button>
<p>
  Original Text:
  <textarea id="input">GDS in the beginning, inthePHPmiddle, but PHP works. Also, JS. GDS for good measure.</textarea>
</p>
<p>
  New Text:
  <textarea id="output"></textarea>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the replace method of the string object: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

You'll have to use a regular expression to replace all occurrences.

```
var boxText = document.getElementById("textBox").value // Get what's in the TextBox.

var newBoxText = boxText.replace(/Initial/g, "Updated");

document.getElementById("bottomText").innerHTML = newBoxText
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rny94z4j/

Comment: This looks like it would work. Now I just need to find a way to scan the textbox and search for the strings.

Comment: The replace method will do this for you, please see my updated answer & jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the `replace` method:

```
boxText = boxText.replace(/\bGDS\b/g, 'Good Domestic Standard');
```

The `\b` matches a word boundary, so that it mathces the code name standing by itself, and not as part of another word.

To replace multiple strings, you can use a pattern that matches any of the strings, and use a callback function to choose the replacement:

```
boxText = boxText.replace(/\b(GDS|ADS|PDS)\b/g, function(m){
  switch (m) {
    case 'GDS': return 'Good Domestic Standard';
    case 'ADS': return 'Average Domestic Standard';
    case 'PDS': return 'Poor Domestic Standard';
  }
});
```

Demo:

```js
var boxText = "GDS, ADS, PDS";

boxText = boxText.replace(/\b(GDS|ADS|PDS)\b/g, function(m){
  switch (m) {
    case 'GDS': return 'Good Domestic Standard';
    case 'ADS': return 'Average Domestic Standard';
    case 'PDS': return 'Poor Domestic Standard';
  }
});

// show result in Stackoverflow snippet
document.write(boxText);
```

Comment: if I can stretch it this far, how would I then put the replaced values into the textbox, overwriting the codeword that was originally written?

Comment: @String: If you want to put the string back in the textbox, just use `document.getElementById("textBox").value = boxText;`.

Comment: Yeah, figured this out eventually. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but this should do the trick:

```
function getBoxText() {
// store strings in object to have them easily maintainable
var strings = {
    'GDS' : 'Good Domestic Standard',
    'GTA' : 'Grand Theft Auto',
    'FUBAR' : 'fucked up beyond all recognition'
};

var boxText = document.getElementById("textBox").value;
for (var shortcode in strings) {
    boxText = boxText.replace(shortcode,strings[shortcode]);
}
document.getElementById("bottomText").innerHTML = boxText;
}
```